# How can I disable/dismiss the keyboard on iOS with Appium

Tags: java, ios, automated-tests, appium-ios, appium-java

Is there anyway to dismiss the iPhone keyboard or disable it from popping up at all while Appium tests are being run?

`driver.hideKeyboard()` doesn't work, half the time a "DONE" or "RETURN" button isn't present and I can't just tap randomly on the screen because I can not guarantee that the code won't accidentally tap a link or active element.

I don't understand why it doesn't just function like on Android and just never display the keyboard when using driver.sendKeys().

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same and did a workaround by doing it like an actual user and clicking on the hide keyboard button. You might want to add a check to only click if the element is visible to avoid trying to close the keyboard when it's not there.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("your_keyboard_close_button")).click();
```

Comment: Some field elements dont have a keyboard close button

Comment: If the keyboard is shown, you can check the close button of that keyboard its element selector via the Appium Inspector for example.

Comment: not every instance of the iOS keyboard has a close button....

Comment: There must be something to close/hide the keyboard, no? Or some other user action that might close the keyboard, perhaps by pressing Done on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue.

you can basically try to fix it in two ways:

- click "return" button on keyboard (if available)
- use tap method from TouchAction to tap somewhere on screen, but just make sure that tapping in that spot hides the keyboard